# Fetching floating IP on openstack VM

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

I am trying to automate a service on my VM (which is on openstack cloud) for which I need the floating IP of that machine. Is there a command or anything for that matter which can help me get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for clarification: When you way "you want to get" the floating IP is, you want to know from inside the instance the floating IP attached to it ?. If that's the case, just use the metadata service by either directly using "curl", or if you have the cloud-init tools installed on the instance, use the "ec2metadata" command.

If you instead want to auto-assign the FIP to the instance, the answer above is the right one.

Comment: Thanks, this is the better way of getting FIP.

Comment: @tigerlinux: can you elaborate on how ec2-metadata can be used in openstack to get FIP of the VM?

Comment: Nevermind got it, `ec2metadata --public-ipv4` command did the job. Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Install che `openstack` cli. I used cli version `openstack 2.6.0`.

First create a floating IP. You will need to give the name of your public network. In my case the name is **public**. If unsure about the name of the network where you can get a floating ip from check with

```
openstack network list
```

Create the floating ip

```
$ openstack ip floating create public
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Field               | Value                                |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| fixed_ip_address    | None                                 |
| floating_ip_address | 86.119.0.163                         |
| floating_network_id | 7313f148-f340-49b4-9d76-89de0702e801 |
| headers             |                                      |
| id                  | bba11a1b-9a31-4d67-a339-2fdbb3b74d11 |
| port_id             | None                                 |
| project_id          | 0009b5ca32594503b2d64ded05bbe0a8     |
| router_id           | None                                 |
| status              | DOWN                                 |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
$
```

Now that you have a floating IP you can associate it to the VM using the VM name. You can check the vm name with the command

```
openstack server list
```

Associate the floating IP

```
openstack ip floating add 86.119.0.163 vmname
```

If you do again `openstack server list` you will see that now the IP is listed associate to the VM.

I think you are interested now in

```
openstack server show vmname -f json
```

Will return a lot of information about the VM and also the addresses. Check the `-f` flag, there are more formatters than json